# Python: Cannot construct empty GeoDataFrame with columns

Tags: python, geopandas, attributeerror

My script

```
import geopandas as gp
test = gp.GeoDataFrame(columns=['geometry', 'costs'])
```

the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 89, in__init__ super(GeoDataFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
file "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 348, in __init__ 
mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 451, in _init_dict                                                                                                                      nan_dtype)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1196, in construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar
dtype = dtype.dtype
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

What could be the reason for that? It always worked for me like that. Now I had a software update and it suddenly does not work anymore.

Comment: Please add geopandas and pandas version

Comment: Works for me `geopandas.show_versions()` -> `[...] python: 3.9.1 [...] GDAL: 2.4.4 [...] geopandas: 0.8.2 [...] pandas: 1.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

Had the wrong pandas version.

```
pip3 install pandas == 1.2.2
```

fixed it for me